# Android App Not Working after updating aide id

Tags: android

Hello i am trying to fetch some data from database and after updating aide ide my app crash unexpectedly. Here is log.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
 AndroidRuntime                               Process: com.androbaron.materialnews, PID: 16246
 AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
  AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
 AndroidRuntime                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
 AndroidRuntime                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
 AndroidRuntime                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
 AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
 AndroidRuntime                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
   AndroidRuntime                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
  AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method execute(Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest;)Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/CloseableHttpResponse; in class Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)
 AndroidRuntime                               at com.androbaron.materialnews.json.JSONStream.getJsonResult(JSONStream.java:54)
 AndroidRuntime                               at com.androbaron.materialnews.data.RecipeLoader.doInBackground(RecipeLoader.java:33)
 AndroidRuntime                               at com.androbaron.materialnews.data.RecipeLoader.doInBackground(RecipeLoader.java)
   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
 AndroidRuntime                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
 AndroidRuntime                               ... 4 more
```

RecipeLoader.java

```
@Override
protected List<Recipe> doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<>();
        JsonReader reader = jsonStream.getJsonResult(URL, JSONStream.METHOD_GET, param);
        return getRecipeArray(reader);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return null;
}
```

JSONStream.java

```
public JsonReader getJsonResult(String url, String method,List<NameValuePair> params) {
    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // check for request method
        if(method == METHOD_POST){
            // request method is POST / defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == METHOD_GET){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            //Log.d("url", url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
        //Log.e("ERRRR", "E : " + inputStreamReader.toString());
        jsonReader = new JsonReader(inputStreamReader);
        return jsonReader;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Anyone solve this problem? 
I am new in android development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this into app build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.example1"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        useLibrary "org.apache.http.legacy"
    }
```